# Python api for taking picture from a webcam on a Linux machine

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

Im using ubuntu 11.04 on my Lenovo Thinkpad machine. Is there a python api for taking a picture programmatically from the webcam ? . Some example would be really appreciated.

Please Help
Thank You

Answer (score 4):

opencv has python wrappers
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/index.html

Answer (score 2):

There is a package here: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/v4l2

You might also want to study the [Video4Linux 2 API specification](http://v4l2spec.bytesex.org/).